# select the dates when a customer doesn't meet the requirements in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of "customers", "count" and "datefield". I want to get the dates when a customer has a "count" of below 100. If the "count" remains below 100 then I am expecting only the first date when the "count" dropped below 100. If the "count" goes back up to 100 and drops again, I need that date when the "count" dropped below 100 again.

example data:

| Customer | Count | datefield |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 99 | 1/2/2019 |
| A | 105 | 21/2/2019 |
| A | 69 | 02/3/2019 |
| A | 68 | 12/3/2019 |
| A | 160 | 14/3/2019 |
| A | 79 | 21/3/2019 |

I am expecting a SQL statement which would return the times the customer had a count below 100.

Expected result:

| Customer | Count | datefield |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 99 | 1/2/2019 |
| A | 69 | 02/3/2019 |
| A | 79 | 21/3/2019 |

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please include your query/queries in the question.

Comment: This site is not a code-writing service. We can help you with *specific* questions about *your* code, ideally accompanied by an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the previous count per customer.
Which you can get via the `LAG` function.

> ```
> SELECT q.Customer, q.Count, q.datefield
> FROM
> (
>   SELECT *
>   , LAG(t.Count) OVER (PARTITION BY t.Customer ORDER BY t.datefield) AS prev_count
>   FROM your_table t
> ) q
> WHERE q.Count < 100 AND coalesce(q.prev_count,100) >= 100
> ORDER BY q.Customer, q.datefield;
> ```

| customer | count | datefield |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 99 | 2019-02-01 |
| A | 69 | 2019-03-02 |
| A | 79 | 2019-03-21 |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0cb1af9dea1ed63ba419d37cbed48350)*

Comment: you are a genius! this worked, thanks!